# Создание select через объект

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста, в чём ошибка.
Я хочу создать объект, который будет стилизовать select.
Я передаю в него контейнер, и нужные option а он создаёт мне li.
Но почему то он мне возвращает не те значения, в обоих селектах у меня  из первого.
Есть подозрение что ошибка где-то с 23 по 28 строку, скрорее всего там нужен this, но не понимаю как нужно реализовать. Если кто создавал похожее, подскажите пожалуйста
Ниже предоставлена ссылка на мой набросок:
https://codepen.io/MynameisIM/pen/BPKgod

```
  for (var i = 0; i < optionsItem.length; i++) {
    var dropitem = document.createElement('li');
    dropitem.classList.add('select__item');
    dropitem.textContent = optionsItem[i].value;
    dropdown.append(dropitem);  
  }
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PBzYjP

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko Привесьма благодарен, Ваш код действительно работает, но я никак не пойму в чём же была моя ошибка...я просмотрел код, вроде бы он совпадает, но у Вас работает, а у меня нет...Если есть возможность, подскажите...

Comment: Нашёл ошибку...прошу прощения за беспокойство!

Comment: Автор, у тебя просто одинаковые названия в селектах :). 
PS Не заметил что уже новый коммент появился...

Answer (score 0):

Я в codepen вижу, что все отображается, как задумано автором. Два списка с полями с первого по восьмое. Единственное, теги select содержат один и тот же id. Если дальше select будем искать по id, могут быть конфликты.